# How to provide enclave argument when running with launch file

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to enable SROS2 on our existing ROS2 nodes, which use launch files.

I have created a keystore and keys for the node and now I'm wondering how to pass a pointer to these when launching the node.

Basically I suppose I want to find a launch file equivalent for this cli sample command:

```
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker --ros-args --enclave /talker_listener/talker
```

Our existing launch file is rather simple and looks like this:

```
<launch>
  <node name="control_node" pkg="ros2node_ctrl" exec="ros2node_ctrl" namespace='$(env NODE_DEVICE>
    <param name="udp_remote_port" value="xxxxx"/>
    <param name="target_ip" value="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

I tried adding a parameter with name "enclave" in the launch file but didn't seem to work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373390/how-to-provide-enclave-argument-when-running-with-launch-file/) by [quinz](https://answers.ros.org/users/71409/quinz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2021-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Managed to solve this by adding `--ros-args` as "args" in the `<node>`:

```
<node name="control_node" pkg="ros2node_ctrl" exec="ros2node_ctrl" args="--ros-args --enclave $(env NODE_ENCLAVE)" namespace='$(env NODE_DEVICE)'>
```

---

Originally posted by [quinz](https://answers.ros.org/users/71409/quinz/) with karma: 18 on 2021-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wienans](https://answers.ros.org/users/70396/wienans/) on 2022-12-12**:
@quinz you should mark this as answere so others can see that the question was answered

**Comment by [quinz](https://answers.ros.org/users/71409/quinz/) on 2022-12-12**:
Good point @wienans. Done :)